# Which card combinations are required to score 29 points in a hand?

Tags: cribbage

In the game of Cribbage, which card combinations are required to score 29 points in hand in the game of cribbage? If there are multiple, please list in decending order.

Comment: There's just one hand, and you can search for "29 points in cribbage" to see that hand.

Comment: @TheChaz2.0 And if this question is answered, then the search results will include this question. So I don't see the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Board & Card Games Stack Exchange! Please take [the tour](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/tour) if you haven't already. I've made a few edits to your question to clarify the title and to make it sound more like a question, rather than a command. If you don't like my changes, feel free to edit or revert them.

Comment: @Thunderforge it definitely gets the -1 for "This question does not show any research effort"

Comment: @BenjaminCosman And I would argue that we should give some slack to new users instead of downvoting their posts to oblivion. Stack Overflow/Exchange has a problem with welcoming new users, and bad first impressions like this are one of the reasons. Heck, we just had [a blog post about that very topic](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/).

Comment: Fair enough; I probably shouldn't have done that. Instead of my downvote or your this-question-is-totally-fine comment, we probably want something in between - "Welcome to the site and thanks for your question! Someone will probably write up an answer soon, but for now I'd check out the first google result for "29 points cribbage" (and I'd encourage you to always try google first - there are many questions it can answer a lot faster than we can!)"

Answer (score 8):

The only hand that will score a 29 consists of all four 5s and the Jack of nobs.

The scoring of this hand is nicely broken down in [this Cribbage Corner post](http://cribbagecorner.com/scoring-29-hand):

> We score the 29 hand in the same way as any other: taking 15s first, then pairs, runs, flushes and nobs.
>
> First count 15s. The Jack makes 15 with each of the 5s, that's 4 15s. Also, there are 4 ways of choosing three different 5s to make additional 15s. That's 8 in total, for 16 points.
>
> Then pairs: there are 6 different pairs of 5s, for another 12 points. That's 28 so far.
>
> There are no runs or flushes, so the Jack of nobs gives us a final point for 29.